# Bounty on my question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, bounty

I have put a 50 point bounty on my question [If photons have no rest mass, where does Planck's constant come from?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/731002/) 3 days ago. 4 days are left before the bounty expires. However, I have not yet received an answer there I cannot understand why people are getting so late to answer my question during the bounty period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a thing that happens. A bounty increases the visibility of a question, but doesn’t guarantee that it’ll be seen by a person who knows a good answer and is willing to take the time to write it up. I’ve certainly had failed bounties of my own, both on my questions and on others’.

If your bounty expires, you can add another one afterwards. Be aware that subsequent bounties cost more reputation points.

Comment: It is unlikely that an unanswered question will not receive an answer during the bounty period. However, a question with an already accepted answer may deter other users from posting another answer.

Comment: Several of the bounty reasons invite additional answers. If you are putting a bounty on your *own* question, and you have already accepted an answer which doesn’t meet your needs, that is a confusing use of the system.

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya Why do you say it's unlikely an unanswered question will not receive an answer during the bounty period? If the question is simply tough to answer, then there's a fairly good chance it won't be answered during the bounty period. That's always a risk one takes with bounties. Some questions out there are well-posed but will never get answers. It's frustrating but there's nothing you can do

Comment: @Jim I went by the answer at [my question from the HSM meta](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360/bounties-on-my-question) site: [HSM question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/12469/names-of-the-electromagnetic-units-in-si).

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya I see. It might be worth noting that HSM isn't Physics

Comment: @Jim It is true HSM isn't Physics. However, there are general rules for every network question as explained at https://meta.stackexchange.com/.